# Ошибка при вводе массива данных в БД

Tags: php

Вот форма ввода данных.

```
<tr>
                                              <th> Артикул</th><th> Наименование</th><th> Количество</th><th> Ед. измерения</th><th> Стоимость</th><th> Сумма</th></tr>
                                          <?$a=2; For ($i=1; $i<$a; $i++){?>
                                              <tr>
                                                  <th><input type="text" name="items[<?= $i; ?>][code]" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Артикул"></th>
                                                  <th><input type="text" name="items[<?= $i; ?>][name]" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Наименование"></th>
                                                  <th><input type="text" name="items[<?= $i; ?>][quantity]" value="" id="quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="Количество"></th>
                                                  <th><input type="text" name="items[<?= $i; ?>][unit]" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Ед. измерения"></th>
                                                  <th><input type="text" name="items[<?= $i; ?>][cost]" id="cost" class="form-control" placeholder="Стоимость"></th>
                                                  <th><input type="text" name="items[<?= $i; ?>][sum]" id="sum" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Сумма"></th>
                                              </tr>
                                          <? }?>
```

Вот здесь данные обрабатываются и вносятся в базу данных.

```
if (isset($_POST['items'])){ 
    foreach ($_POST['items'] as $item) {
    $code = trim($item['code']);
    $name = trim($item['name']);
    $quantity = trim($item['quantity']);
    $unit = trim($item['unit']);
    $cost = trim($item['cost']);
    $sum = trim($item['sum']);


        $insert_query = "INSERT INTO stok_product (code, quantity, name, unit, cost, sum, date ) VALUES ('$code','$quantity','$name','$unit','$cost','$sum',NOW())";
        $result_insert = mysqli_query($link, $insert_query);
}
}

?>
```

В итоге почему в базу вводятся только первый и последний элементы массива.
А так же есть вот такая ошибка
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1
Может кто-то сталкивался и знает в чем проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще не рекомендуется использовать короткие теги `<? ... ?>`, у меня они даже отключены по умолчанию, из-за этого слегка изменил Ваш код:

```php
<?php $a = 3; for ($i = 1; $i < $a; $i++) : ?>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="text" name="items[<?= $i ?>][code]" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Артикул"></th>
        <th><input type="text" name="items[<?= $i ?>][name]" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Наименование"></th>
        <th><input type="text" name="items[<?= $i ?>][quantity]" value="" id="quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="Количество"></th>
        <th><input type="text" name="items[<?= $i ?>][unit]" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Ед. измерения"></th>
        <th><input type="text" name="items[<?= $i ?>][cost]" id="cost" class="form-control" placeholder="Стоимость"></th>
        <th><input type="text" name="items[<?= $i ?>][sum]" id="sum" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Сумма"></th>
    </tr>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

После запуска с вводом рандомных значений вывел сгенерированные запросы:

```sql
INSERT INTO `stok_product` (`code`, `quantity`, `name`, `unit`, `cost`, `sum`, `date`) VALUES ('4567','5678','45678','4567','4567','4567',NOW())
INSERT INTO `stok_product` (`code`, `quantity`, `name`, `unit`, `cost`, `sum`, `date`) VALUES ('4567','567','4567','4567','567','5678',NOW())
```

Как я понимаю, эти SQL запросы должны быть корректны (но по факту не проверял).
Также советую не использовать прямой ввод от пользователя при добавлении данных в БД, для этого есть `mysqli_prepare(...)`, потому что при вводе строки, например, с символом `'` весь запрос сломается